# How to determine if elliptic equation comes from variational problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, elliptic-equations

Is there any criteria to determine if a elliptic equation comes from energy minimizing problem? For example, if I have a elliptic equation in divergence form $\nabla \cdot A(x,u,\nabla u)+|\nabla u|=0$ (Supposed that I have found the the energy for the term  $\nabla \cdot A(x,u,\nabla u)$). Is this equation has no variational structure? How about the general form $\nabla \cdot A(x,u,\nabla u)+B(x,u,\nabla u)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

If the equation is of the form 
$$
\nabla \cdot A(x,u,\nabla u) + B(x,u,\nabla u) =0,
$$then such an equation can be brought into variational form by integration by parts.

The corresponding natural boundary condition would be of the type
$$
A(x,u,\nabla u) \cdot \nu = 0.
$$
If the boundary condition has a different form then it might be again difficult to bring the equation into variational form.

An equation of the type
$$
-a(x)\Delta u(x)=f(x)
$$
with non-smooth $a$ is hard to bring into a variational form, which allows for an easy solution theory.

Comment: Thank you so much! If we consider the Dirichlet energy $\int_V |\nabla u|^2=0$, the minimizing equation would the Laplacian equation. But Is there any energy functional gives us the minimizing equation $|\nabla u|=0$? (I dont want to take square of the gradient since my equation is linear combination of terms consisting$ |\nabla u|$)